# What is the 'old style' syntax for joins in T-Sql?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, legacy-code

I'm rewriting a bunch of old, badly written Oracle queries against a new(-er) Sql Server 2008 environment. They use old-school Oracle join syntax like

```
select <whatever>
from Table1, Table2, Table3
where Table1.T1ID = Table2.T2ID      -- old Oracle inner join
and   Table2.T3ID = Table3.T3ID (+)  -- old Oracle left join (I think)
```

Except a lot more complicated. There's a lot of mixed joins and a lot of nesting and a lot of views piled on views going on in these things. It's not pretty. The data is disparate between the two servers too, making testing a chore.

I figured the easiest way to replicate would be to make the queries look as similar as possible in Sql Server (ie, using the same style of join), and then do a massive clean-up job after once I'm confident they're both definitely doing the same thing & I don't have a join in the wrong place somewhere (and yes, I have compatibility mode temporarily set to support old joins).

I know the 'old' syntax for an inner join in T-Sql is

```
select <whatever>
from T1, T2
where T1.ID = T2.ID
```

but what is the 'old' syntax for a left outer join or a right outer join?

Comment: It is worth noting that the non-ANSI outer join operators (`*=` and `=*`) have been deprecated since SQL Server 2005, if you want to use these in SQL Server 2008, you will need to set the compatibility level of your database to 80. This could cause many other processes to fail, you will probably need to just bite the bullet and rewrite with the ANSI92 join syntax straight away.

Comment: I'm aware - in the question: `(and yes, I have compatibility mode temporarily set to support old joins).` :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the documentation on [TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa213235(v=sql.80).aspx) (on SQL Server 2000, so be aware this might not be supported any more!), you need to use `*=` instead of the `(+)` as Oracle does:

```
select <whatever>
from T1, T2
where T1.ID *= T2.ID
```

Comment: @OzrenTkalcecKrznaric: Thanks. I think you should avoid using this. Why would you want to? Added notice in my answer.

Comment: I would avoid it too; however, I would use the same strategy for code rewriting as OP (2 passes), to avoid breaking the code by changing the select behavior. If I have to rewrite 2-3 queries I could take my chance, but if it's 200-300 queries... :/

Comment: Yep. It's not intended to be kept in the long term at all. As soon as I'm confident the joins are doing the same thing, I'm rewriting all the code to something much more sensible. I have compatibility mode temporarily set.